# CSS "Nowrap" doesn't work properly

Tags: css, nowrap

I'm currently building an email template. The template contains USP's that are lined next to each other. This is the code I'm using:

```
<td width="100%">
  <span style="white-space: nowrap;">
    <img src="checkmark.png" />&nbsp;&nbsp;[text name="USP1"]
  </span>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <span style="white-space: nowrap;">
    <img src="checkmark.png" />&nbsp;&nbsp;[text name="USP2"]
  </span>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <span style="white-space: nowrap;">
    <img src="checkmark.png" />&nbsp;&nbsp;[text name="USP3"]
  </span>
</td>
```

With the "nowrap" I'm trying to put the USP's underneath each other on smartphones. Too bad the USP's all stand next to each other, which makes the table wider.

Is there a simple inline-CSS trick to make them stand under each other on small screens?

Comment: Could you put each into its own `<tr>`?

Comment: A live example would help, I couldn't tell what you are trying to do from a quick glance. But I gave up as soon as I saw `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`, please don't format using spaces...

Comment: nowrap = Sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace. Text will never wrap to the next line. The text continues on the same line until a <br> tag is encountered

Answer (score 2):

**HTML:**

```
<td class="usps">
  <span>...
</td>
```

**CSS:**

```
table tr td.usps span {
  display: block;
}
```